# Is it able for NestJS to show show the error with description?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm new to NestJS. I normally dev on JAVA but I need to go with NestJS due to the project requirement. I'm using NestJS + TypeORM + SQLSERVER.

When I test on my code, I got the SQL ERROR like this,

```
2023-09-27T17:44:50.134Z error:    Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

I know it is about the length error but is there anyway to enable the NestJS to show more details about the error ?

Like JAVA, it will show where the error is located whit really help developers to spot the error.

Really thanks for every comments, supports & helps

Comment: You're looking for the stack trace, and depending on how you log the error, it's usually there

Comment: Can you provide more context? Where is error appearing? On the server terminal, or in the tests? In what environment? Can you show what's around this error?